# Get user information from Azure Active Directory sign in when serving up HTML only Angular 4

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

Currently I have a web app secured with Azure Active Directory forcing the user to login once and then be given access to the application.  The application is an Angular 4 application and therefore an html page is served up from the web app and there isn't any server side code.  The API code is hosted on another web app and thus CORs is enabled for the UI to access the API.

The issue I am having is retrieving user information from Azure Active Directory within the Angular 2 app.  Is this possible?  What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. User logs into Azure Active Directory
2. **My app somehow knows who the current user is, e.g. username, user email,
   maybe even the bearer token? (this is the part I need help with, is this even possible?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an endpoint where you can get user info when using Easy Auth with App Service:

```
/.auth/me
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#working-with-user-identities-in-your-application)

Try it from our front-end, I haven't tried this scenario, but it might work.

Another way would be to integrate Azure AD auth in your Angular app in the front-end code, rather than using the Easy Auth of App Service.

Example app (Angular 2): https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/ng2-adal-QuickStart.

Adal makes the integration fairly easy.

Comment: this is the answer, how do I mark it as the answer?

Comment: There should be a checkmark under the up and down vote buttons :) Glad it helped!